# Unity Android Gallery

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, android-gallery

Quite new to android development so hope some1 can enlighten me. Did a fair share of googling but still stuck. I am using Unity 4 and Eclipse, trying to display the Image Gallery and retrieve the Uri of the image. (Note: I am using Prime31's android social network plugin)

At first, I did not extend UnityPlayerActivity, but I realised I am unable to get onActivityResult if I don't extend it.
After extending, I am getting "Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()". Tried runonuithread and did not work, but might be due to my in-experience in using it. So hope you guys can help.

The following is what I have done in Eclipse:

```
public class AndroidGalleryPlugin extends UnityPlayerActivity{

public static AndroidGalleryPlugin plugin_instance;
public Uri ImageURI;
static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;

static Context _context;

public static AndroidGalleryPlugin instance ()
{
    if(plugin_instance == null)
        plugin_instance = new AndroidGalleryPlugin();
    return plugin_instance;
}

private AndroidGalleryPlugin () {}

public static void StartOpenGallery (Context mContext)
{
    Log.d("AndroidGalleryPlugin", "Start Open Gallery");
    _context = mContext;
    Intent intent = new Intent ();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    Activity activity = (Activity) _context;
    activity.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    Log.d("AndroidGalleryPlugin", "onActivityResult");
}

// And to convert the image URI to the direct file system path of the image file
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {

    Log.d("AndroidGalleryPlugin", "Get URI");
}
```

}

Code In Unity:

```
jc = new AndroidJavaClass ("com.asd.androidgallery.AndroidGallery");
jo = jc.CallStatic <AndroidJavaObject> ("instance");

if(jo == null)
{
    Debug.LogError ("Java Obj Null");
    return false;
}

unityClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
unityObj = unityClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");

if(unityObj == null)
{
    Debug.LogError ("Unity Obj Null");
    return false;
}

jo.CallStatic("StartOpenGallery", unityObj);
```

This is my androidmanifest:

```
<activity android:name="com.prime31.UnityPlayerNativeActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
  <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
  <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
</activity>

 <activity android:name="com.asd.androidgallery.AndroidGalleryPlugin" android:configChanges="orientation"></activity>
```

Comment: There is also plugins that does the same thing, such as "Native Gallery Assist" - (https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/60922) It works for both Android as well as iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some changes, first for your java code

```
public class AndroidGalleryPlugin extends UnityPlayerActivity{

public Uri ImageURI;
static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
private Activity _activity;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    super.onCreate(arg0);
    _activity = UnityPlayer.currentActivity;
}

public static void StartOpenGallery (Context mContext)
{
    Log.d("AndroidGalleryPlugin", "Start Open Gallery");
    _context = mContext;
    Intent intent = new Intent ();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    _activity.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    Log.d("AndroidGalleryPlugin", "onActivityResult");
}

// And to convert the image URI to the direct file system path of the image file
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {

    Log.d("AndroidGalleryPlugin", "Get URI");
}
```

Added `onCreate` method which I get Unity's current activity from there. Also the constructor methods are unnecessary for your class since its an activity.

For Unity since you are overriding your activity you just need to get your get your unityplayer class not the instance! Just use this code.

```
unityClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
unityObj = unityClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");

if(unityObj == null)
{
    Debug.LogError ("Unity Obj Null");
    return false;
}

unityObj.CallStatic("StartOpenGallery");
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Any idea how to solve the main problem though?

Comment: Hi @nexx, I followed your suggestion and removed the instance. However, I am catching an exception no static method "StartOpenGallery" in class UnityPlayerNativeActivity. Oh I forgot to mentioned, I am using some plugins from Prime31.

Comment: Ohh I can't tell about Prime31 plugins, never used before. But maybe your problem is from your AndroidManifest file. Have you added your `AndroidGalleryPlugin` to your manifest and marked it as launcher?

Comment: I have added AndroidGalleryPlugin as an activity but Prime31 took up the launcher activity. I will update in the main post. Please help me and take a look. Thanks for all the time spend guiding me.

Comment: Yes the plugin overrides the unity activity by default. Maybe the [plugins own documentation](https://prime31.com/docs#androidSocial) will help. [You can try these Instructions](https://gist.github.com/prime31/0908e6100d7e228f1add)

Answer (score 0):

Just Use "Android Native Gallery Item Picker" Plugin. It can pick single or multiple image and video from your android phone or android gallery.

[Click here for Android Native Gallery Item Picker](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/android-native-gallery-item-picker-115825)